# Using component with slot inside v-for

Tags: vue.js, components, slot, v-for

I need to render a component with a slot inside a v-for loop like so:

```
<div v-for="(data,index) in myList" :key="index">
    <datepicker v-model="data.thru">
        <div slot="beforeCalendarHeader" @click="selectToday" class="today p-2 text-center">
            Today
        </div>
    </datepicker>
</div>
```

and i get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Duplicate presence of slot "beforeCalendarHeader" found in the same render tree - this will likely cause render errors.
```

How i can use the componentns slot inside the loop?

**Sample:**
https://codepen.io/DivDax/pen/ajoWPY

Comment: What version of Vue? Can you write a small demo?

Comment: created a sample: https://codepen.io/DivDax/pen/ajoWPY

Comment: That appears to be a bug in the datepicker library. The `beforeCalendarHeader` slot is specified 3 times in the code. It does not appear to me to have anything to do with your loop. You get the same error if you use a single datepicker. https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/blob/master/src/components/Datepicker.vue